# uib-pagination not paging correctly when new line is added

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I have a table of people showing and if there are more than 3 then the pagination controls should show. I want to allow the user to add/delete people to/from that table.

I have been able to add and delete from the table, and if there are 3 or less people, they display correctly. If I add a fourth person, I would expect the pagination control to go to the 2nd page and the top row. What appears to happen though is the pagination control, will show a '2' for a possible page number, but the 4th person shows on the first page....all others added also go to the first page. It seems as though the page numbers at the bottom do not work - the page doesn't change. I do update the current page value, but it doesn't seem like it is being reflected.

Below is a portion of my View. There are some extra pieces in it that don't really relate to paging.  I use them to get to the right line to provide the user an input field to enter an employee name if the Add Lead button was clicked. Once they find who they are looking for, then the values are just displayed.

```
<table class="table" >
  <tbody ng-repeat="boLead in components[selectedRow].boleads " pagination-id="boleads" >
    <tr >                                   
        <td id="leadId" >{{boLead.boLeadId}}</td>
        <td ng-show="(inserted == boLead && newLead) ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="boLead.boLead" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 800 }' ng-change="searchEmployee(boLead.boLead)" /> 
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" ng-show="employees.length">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee ID</th>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="result in employees" ng-click="pickEmployee(result, boLead)">
                        <td>{{result.user_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{result.name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </td>
        <td ng-show="(inserted != boLead && !editq  || (editq && editl != ($index+(3*(pagination.current-1)))) )">{{boLead.boLead}}</td>
        <td ng-if="mode == 'edit'">
            <select  class="form-control input-md" ng-model="boLead.forwardONS" >
                <option>Yes</option>
                <option>No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td ng-if="mode == 'edit' && (!checkNewLead(boLead) && !editq)">
            <button type="button" ng-click="removeLead($index+(3*(pagination.current-1)))" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash"> Delete</button>
        </td>
        <td ng-if="mode == 'view'" ng-bind-html="boLead.forwardONS"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<uib-pagination  previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;" ng-model="pagination.current"  class="pagination-sm" ng-if="pagination.totalLeads > 3" items-per-page="3" total-items="pagination.totalLeads" boundary-link-numbers="true"></uib-pagination>
```

Controller:
This is the portion for adding a person to the list

```
    $scope.addLead = function() {
    $scope.inserted = {
        prgGuid: $scope.components[$scope.selectedRow].prgGuid,
        componentId: $scope.components[$scope.selectedRow].componentId,
        boLeadId: '',
        boLead : '',
        forwardONS: ''
    };

    if (typeof $scope.components[$scope.selectedRow].boleads == 'undefined') {

        $scope.components[$scope.selectedRow].boleads = new Array($scope.inserted);
    } else {

        $scope.components[$scope.selectedRow].boleads.push($scope.inserted);
    }

    $scope.newLead = true;
    $scope.editq = true;
    $scope.editl = $scope.components[$scope.selectedRow].boleads.length-1;
    if ($scope.components[$scope.selectedRow].boleads.length > 3) {
        var pg = Math.ceil($scope.components[$scope.selectedRow].boleads.length / 3);
        $scope.pagination.current = pg;
    }
    $scope.pagination.totalLeads = $scope.components[$scope.selectedRow].boleads.length;
};
```

When I step through this, the $scope.pagination.current = pg; does update properly with what the current page should be. For instance, once a 4th person is added, it becomes 2. This is the ng-model in the pagination controls, but it just doesn't seem like the pagination is listening, since the screen doesn't change to show the new line but instead all four show.

I've looked at a lot of posts, but I seem to be doing something different than everyone - I couldn't find an example of someone adding a line and then the screen page when enough entries would require going to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have been able to fix my problem after looking at more examples...I added a slice to the table and it seems to work exactly how I wanted...

I changed this line:

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="boLead in components[selectedRow].boleads " pagination-id="boleads" >
```

to:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="boLead in components[selectedRow].boleads.slice(((pagination.current-1)*3), ((pagination.current)*3)) " pagination-id="boleads" >
```